# Login problem laravel 7 partially solved but why?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

When trying to login nothing happens but an error occurs i laravel.log. This is my project converted from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 7.29.

The error:

```
local.ERROR: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Here is the statement in app/Models/User.php where the error happens  (return....) (In laravel 5.3 it works like a charm.)

```
public function getClubsIdAttribute()
{
if(!$this->relationLoaded('Clubs')):  $this->load('Clubs');
       endif;
       return (count($this->Clubs->first())) ? $this->Clubs->first()->id : null;
}
```

Clubs are pistol competition clubs, about 800 different around the country. They are stored in database as posts. But when I login I do not have to be connected to any club.

I got a solution to the problem by a friend like this:

```
public function getClubsIdAttribute()
{
  if (isset($this->Clubs) && $this->Clubs->first()) return $this->Clubs->first()->id;
    else return null;
}
```

and with that I can login. The question i what is the original statement doing and why doesn't that work?

I'm using php 7.3.33

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: `first` will return a Model from the Collection or `null` (both of these can **not** be passed to `count`) ..... don't know why you would use `count` for that any way ... on a side note, checking if the relationship is loaded then loading it if not isn't doing anything for you since accessing the dynamic property loads it anyway, so it will get loaded if it isn't already loaded regardless

Comment: Using php 7.3.33 and lagbox, can you explain why it works well in laravel 5.3 and not in 7.29?

Comment: mrhn - in 5.3 we use php 7.1

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a lot by just doing:

```php
public function getClubsIdAttribute()
{
    return optional($this->Clubs->first())->id;
}
```

Also some side notes:

- The error you got is self-explanatory: `count(null)` is invalid code. The argument must be a Countable (like an array). It also makes no sense to use a `count($object->first())` unless `$object` is a nested array like `collect([['a'],['b']])`;
- Laravel code style likes all relations to be defined in camelCase, so start with a lowercase character.
- The design of your code is a bit odd: you have a `Clubs` relation but for the `clubs_id` you always pick the first club? You might just as well create a new relation like so, which retrieves less data from the database (this should also work properly if you preload this relation for a bunch of users):

```php
public function firstClub()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Club::class)->oldest('id');
}
```

```php
public function getClubsIdAttribute()
{
    return optional($this->firstClub)->id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your first line of code works as well. The fun thing is that in the database we have a clubs table. But even if it's completely empty with clubs it's no problem to login. So I don't understand at all what the statements are good for.

Comment: i have no knowledge about your codebase whatsoever so I cant help with that sadly

Comment: Why use `optional()` when PHP does this for you? `$this->Clubs->first()?->id` or just properly deal with the error: `$this->Clubs->firstOrFail()->id`

Comment: thats even better probably :) (I didnt even know PHP had the `prop()?` syntax (I know about the double `??` though). `firstOrFail()` is also an option but I tend not to use it in many cases, since it throws a 404 in the default exception handler

Comment: Just looked it up, that question mark is the 'nullsafe operator` and its fo PHP >=8.0 (OP says he's using PHP 7.3)